# Embeding a (YouTube) video on landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

We'd like to embed a (e.g. YouTube) video on a landing page in Marketing Cloud Web Studio. We tried using Microsites (Classic Content), but we had problems with rendering on different devices, so we would like to use Content Builder with landing pages. I also tried inserting iframe to an html block, but the video woulnd't play (maybe I did it wrong, or was it the case of security protocols of our company). Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, is it probably linked to your security settings. Try it on your personal phone.

I did a quick test and could use the iframe provided by Youtube. I pasted it in an HTML block (content builder) and it worked on both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Ok. I got it working too. Can you help me on how to get it centered on the landing page (CSS part of the code) ?

Comment: You can use some basic CSS to do that. Just put the iframe in a Div for example: <div style="text-align:center;"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/oHg5SJYRHA0" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen=""></iframe></div>